# Viewport render is correct while rendering scene shows materials as white

Tags: rendering

For some reason when I use the active render in my viewport everything is shown as it should. Then when I actually render the image some of my objects are shown as completely white.

I can't for the life of me figure out why. One of my objects has a texture as well that works perfectly in the viewport render but when I render the scene not only does it show up as only white but it shows no texture whatsoever.

Please help. I've searched through many forums and have not been able to run across anyone else having this problem.

Here is a sample:

[image]

Comment: in the render_layers tab there is a material it should be empty, it is used to replace all materials in this layer

Comment: Yes, I saw that some people were having a problem akin to mine but I did check that and it is indeed empty. My problem lies somewhere else...

Comment: I don't mind posting some pictures as maybe that would expedite things and help those gracious enough to try and help me find a solution to this problem. I don't however know how to post pics... Also I wouldn't mind posting my blend file either but it is a fairly complicated scene (in excess of 80mb) and I read on pasteall that the cap is 30mb

Comment: when you are editing your question you'll see small picture click it to upload one,  for the blend file remove almost everything except some objects to demonstrate the problem and upload it on [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: ok here is a simple blend file. [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=149" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/149/)

Comment: In hindsight I am uncertain if that blend file contains the pictures I used to create that texture. (I'm not sure how to make sure it does either...) I thoroughly appreciate your help thus far Chebhou. If you check out the file though you'll see that in the viewport set to active render it works, and when you actually render it will be all white or even completely transparent.

Comment: problem 1 : the infinite ground is hidden in the view but visible in the render;  problem 2 : in the `render_layer` tab select the same layers under `layers` as under `scene`, try to  render again

Comment: That fixed it! Ahh thank you so so much Chebhou!! I thoroughly appreciate it. Now that my question has been answered is there a way to close this question so everyone knows it is answered?

Answer (score 2):

One of the objects was hidden in the view but visible in the render  , you have to uncheck the camera icon in the outliner :

[image]

the render layer didn't include all scene layers, excluding some objects from the final render, for this you have to check these layers in the render-layers tab :

[image]